# Obtaining $f$ given $\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) \frac{1}{u-f(i)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

Suppose $g(u)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty f(i) \frac{1}{u-f(i)}$

How do I obtain $f$ given $g$?

Example pair: $g(u)=\frac{\sqrt{u}-\pi  \cot \left(\frac{\pi }{\sqrt{u}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{u}}, f(i)=i^{-2}$

This is a Stieltjes transformation which has an inverse formula in [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stieltjes_transformation) but we can't take the limit here. Is there an approach that works for the example pair?

Comment: Your summand doesn't depend on $i$. Is it $x$ you're summing over perhaps?

Comment: @Icv good catch, fixed

Comment: It cannot be unique, you can rearrange $f(i)$ over any finite set without changing the sum.

Comment: I guess $f$ is a sequence and not a function despite the notations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that it is impossible to exactly get $f$ from $g$ because $g$ deosn't change when we permute the terms of $f$. Indeed, for any permutation $\sigma$ of $\mathbb{N}^*$ and any $u$, $\sum_{i \geqslant 1} \frac{f(i)}{u - f(i)} = \sum_{i \geqslant 1} \frac{f(\sigma(i))}{u - f(\sigma(i))}$ assuming that we have absolute convergence. Therefore, the best we result we could obtain is to know for each $u \in \mathbb{C}$ the number of $i \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $f(i) = u$. Let us call $c(u)$ this number. Notice also that adding some $0$ in the sequence $f$ doesn't change $g$ so we may assume without loss of generality that $f$ doesn't vanish (hence $c(0) = 0$).

Assume that $g$ exists for at least one $u_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. Then, for all $i \in I$, $u_0 \neq f(i)$ and $\frac{f(i)}{u_0 - f(i)} = \frac{1}{\frac{u_0}{f(i)} - 1} \rightarrow 0$ when $i \rightarrow +\infty$. Therefore, $\left|\frac{u_0}{f(i)}\right| \rightarrow +\infty$ so $u_0 \neq 0$ and $f(i) \rightarrow 0$. It implies by the way that $c(z) < +\infty$ for any $z \neq 0$. I will assume for simplicity that the previous sequence converges absolutely, whcih means that $\sum_{i \in I} \left|\frac{f(i)}{u_0 - f(i)}\right| < +\infty$. As $f(i) \rightarrow 0$, $\left|\frac{f(i)}{u_0 - f(i)}\right| \sim \frac{|f(i)|}{|u_0|}$ hence $f \in \mathcal{l}^1$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $i_\varepsilon$ be some index such that $\forall i \geqslant i_\varepsilon, |f(i)| < |u_\varepsilon|$. Let $A_\varepsilon = \{u \in \mathbb{C}||u| \geqslant \varepsilon, \forall i \leqslant i_\varepsilon - 1, |u - f(i)| \geqslant \varepsilon\}$. Then, for all $u \in A_\varepsilon$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i \geqslant 1} \left|\frac{f(i)}{u - f(i)}\right| & = \sum_{i = 1}^{i_\varepsilon - 1} \frac{|f(i)|}{|u - f(i)|} + \sum_{i \geqslant i_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{\left|\frac{u}{f(i)} - 1\right|}\\
& \leqslant \sum_{i = 1}^{i_\varepsilon - 1} \frac{|f(i)|}{\varepsilon} + \sum_{i \geqslant i_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{\left|\frac{u}{f(i)}\right| - 1}\\
& \leqslant \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\sum_{i = 1}^{i_\varepsilon - 1} |f(i)| + \sum_{i \geqslant i_\varepsilon} \frac{1}{\left|\frac{\varepsilon}{f(i)}\right| - 1}.
\end{align*}
This sum doesn't depend on $u$ and since $f(i) \rightarrow 0$, $\frac{1}{\frac{\varepsilon}{|f(i)|} - 1} \sim \frac{|f(i)|}{\varepsilon}$ so the series converges. It proves that $g$ converges normally on each $A_\varepsilon$. Therefore, it exists on the open set $U = \bigcup_{\varepsilon > 0} A_\varepsilon = \mathbb{C}\backslash\{f(\mathbb{N}^*) \cup \{0\}\}$ and the convergence is locally uniform. In particular, $g$ is holomorphic (it is a consequence of Morera theorem for example). If $u \in \mathbb{C}^*$, we can use the same method to prove that $z \mapsto (z - u)g(z)$ is holomorphic arround $u$ because the problematic terms $\frac{f(i)}{z - f(i)}$ where $f(i) = u$ in the sum are cancelled by the factor $z - u$. We deduce that $g$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}^*$ with only simple poles.

Let $u \in \mathbb{C}^*$. Then, as $f(\mathbb{N}^*)\backslash\{0\}$ is discrete in $\mathbb{C}^*$ (because $f$ converges toward $0$), there exists a $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f(\mathbb{N}^*) \cap \overline{B}(u,\varepsilon) \subset \{u\}$. Let $\gamma_u : t \mapsto u + \varepsilon e^{2\mathbf{i}\pi t}$, defined for $0 \leqslant t \leqslant 1$. We have $\mathrm{Ind}_u(\gamma_u) = 1$ and for all $z \in f(\mathbb{N}^*) \cup \{0\}$, $\mathrm{Ind}_z(\gamma_u) = 0$. Moreover, the function $u \mapsto \sum_{i \geqslant 1} \left|\frac{f(i)}{u - f(i)}\right|$ is continuous on $U$ by local uniform convergence thus,
$$
\int_{\gamma_u} \sum_{i \geqslant 1} \left|\frac{f(i)}{z - f(i)}\right| \, dz < +\infty.
$$
We deduce by Fubini theorem that,
$$
\int_{\gamma_u} g(z) \, dz = \sum_{i \geqslant 1} \int_{\gamma_u} \frac{f(i)}{z - f(i)} \, dz = \sum_{i \geqslant 1} 2\mathbf{i}\pi f(i)\delta_{f(i),u} = 2\mathbf{i}\pi uc(u).
$$
And,
$$
\int_{\gamma_u} g(z) \, dz = 2\mathbf{i}\pi\mathrm{Res}_u(g),
$$
by the residue theorem. We deduce that for all $u \neq 0$,
$$
\fbox{$\#(f^{-1}(\{u\})) = \frac{\mathrm{Res}_u(g)}{u}$}
$$

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth response! I've tested it for the case of $f(i)=i^{-2}$ and observe the correct [result](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/286967/217)